# Git Branch name is missing from status bar. How do I get it back?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A couple of days ago I was trying to speed up Visual Studio Code by removing some extensions. I think I have removed an extension that would display the Git branch in the bottom left of the status bar.

Does anyone have any idea how to get it back again?

[image: VSCODE screenshot]

Comment: VSCode won't show up the branches if the repo folder is not trusted and you might get `dubious ownership` error. To show up the branch use `git config --global safe.directory *` and then refresh.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is an extension that controls that.  I believe that is just built into Visual Studio Code.

There is however a right click option on the status bar for hiding this:

[image: status bar option to hide source control]

Do you accidentally have it hidden? If so, just right click the status bar and select "Source Control" to enable it.

---

After update 1.75.1 of Visual Studio Code, this option has been replaced with "Source Control Checkout".  When disabled, the branch is hidden on the status bar:

[image: status bar option to hide source control checkout]

Comment: Using latest version (1.75.1 as of this writing) and right click doesn't have any "Source Control" option.

Comment: @ZayneSHalsall seems they changed it in this update, or maybe a prior update for the matter since I posted this.  I updated my answer.

Comment: [Instructions on how to find status bar settings.](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/status-bar)

Comment: as of writing, the right click Source Control Checkout solution worked!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem fixed itself after I restarted VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ,
It turns out I had DISABLED Git vscode which comes bundled with vscode.
[image: Git extension bundled with vscode]

Answer (score 0):

I originally tried [Timothy G.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72560496/1219280) - I was indeed without the referred option checked - but that alone did not do the job.

I then realized that clicking in VS Code's git side menu option mentioned "No Safe Repos were found" (it claimed my repo was owned by another user). There was a button saying "Manage unsafe repos" and the moment I opened my repo this way, I believe that acted as confirming repo's validity.

I was then finally able to see the branch at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this while using VSCode Remote Development via SSH, I found that simply disconnecting and connecting again caused the branch name to come back.